# Outer Measure and $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega = \Big\{(i, j)\ \big|\ 1\le i,j \le N\Big\}$

Tags: measure-theory, outer-measure, measurable-sets

**Question:**
Let $N\in\mathbb{N}$ and
$$
\Omega = \Big\{(i, j)\ \big|\ 1\le i,j \le N\Big\}\subseteq \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}
$$

Define $\mu^*: \mathcal{P}(\Omega) \to [0, \infty]$ by letting $\mu^*(A)$ be the the number of integers $i$ so that there exists some $j$ with $(i, j) \in A$. 
(a) Show that $\mu^*$ is an outer measure.
(b) Determine the $\sigma$-algebra of all $\mu^*$-measurable sets.

**Attempt:**
From my interpretation of $\mu^*$, it is a function that counts the number of unique $1$st-entry in the set. So, for instance,
$$
\mu^*\bigg(\Big\{(3,7),\ (5,1),\ (3,4)\Big\}\bigg) = 2
$$
since there is only $2$ unique $1$st-entry for this set (namely $3$ and $5$).

I'm able to show that $\mu^*(\emptyset) = 0$ and monotonicity. However, I am running into a bit of trouble showing countable sub-additivity for this outer measure.
$$
\mu^*\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k\right) \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu^*(A_k) \text{ for all } A_k\in\Omega
$$

Also, for (b), I have no idea how to use *Carathéodory's criterion* to determine the $\sigma$-algebra.

**Carathéodory's criterion:**
Let $\mu^*$ be an outer measure on $\Omega$ and
$$
\Sigma = \bigg\{E \subseteq \Omega\ \Big|\ \mu^*(A) = \mu^*(A\cap E) + \mu^*(A\cap E^c)\text{ for all }A\subseteq\Omega\bigg\}
$$
Then $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and $\mu^*$ is a measure on $\Sigma$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $|\Omega|=N^2$ and, thus, $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ is finite and you need to consider only finite unions. For two sets $A_1$ and $A_2$ the number of distinct first coordinates in $A_1\cup A_2$ is clearly less or equal than the sum of that in $A_1$ and $A_2$ individually. Use induction to conclude that the subadditivity holds for any number of sets $A_1,A_2,\ldots, A_k$.

As for (b), consider the collection
$$
\mathcal{F}=\{E\subset \Omega:\mu^*(E)= |E|/N\}.
$$
Basically, if $E\in \mathcal{F}$ and $(i,j)\in E$ for some $j$, then $(i,k)\in E$ for all $k\ne j$. To show that $\mathcal{F}=\Sigma$, notice that if $i$ appears in at least one element of $E$, but $(i,j)\notin E$ for some $j$,
$$
N< \mu^*(\Omega\cap E)+\mu^*(\Omega\cap E^c).
$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. For part (b), I can't quite see how does the definition of $\mathcal{F}$ ensures that Carathéodory criterion is satisfied. More specifically, I can't see why $\mathcal{F}\subseteq\Sigma$ and $\mathcal{F}\supseteq\Sigma$. Do you mind providing more details to elucidate this point?

Comment: @Tham Any such $E\in\mathcal{F}$ ensures that the first coordinates of the points in $A\cap E$ and $A\cap E^c$  are disjoint (for any $A\subset\Omega$), and thus, it satisfies the criterion.

Comment: I think I understand. But this only shows that $\mathcal{F}\subseteq\Sigma$; how does it ensure $\mathcal{F}\supseteq\Sigma$? In other words, how does one ensure that such a definition exhaust all the possible sets that fulfils this the Carathéodory criterion?

Comment: @Tham Oh. Check the last sentence of the answer.

Comment: Got it, thank you so much!